# Asp.Net 5 Mvc 6 Dependency Injection: Register for Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a possibility to register a **service scoped to the Session**?

In the [documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) I found the possibility to add
**Transient**: New instance each time the service is requested
**Scoped**: New instance for each HTTP request
**Singleton**: One instance as long as the server is up and running
**Instance**: Basically a singleton but with the instance I create

But I did not find anything to register a service scoped to the Session.

Is there a workaround for this? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: Sessions are implemented by middleware, so it's not like there is a well-defined *scope* here. What do you want to do?

Comment: What service are you trying to scope this way? Is it one you custom built or one that comes with ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Its one I built myself

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I basically have a class that should save state for each user, so while she stays logged in, the stored data would not vanish. I know I could do this with a database, but its a test application where a database would only complicate things unnecessarily.

Comment: @Domysee but, isn't that what precisely `Microsoft.Aspnet.Session` does? Check out this link: http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/ - specially the "How do I store a complex object?" section.

Comment: Note that Session stores temp data for browser sessions, not login sessions. If you're putting user data in there make sure to clear it if the user signs out, and to set the expirations to match the login cookie. Session is also only a cache, not stable storage.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Thanks a lot for the link. Based on that I'll certainly be able to create a session storage for complex objects (without having to serialize them).

Comment: @Tratcher Thats a good point. At the moment this is not relevant, since the system is still in pre-pre-alpha stage, but I will certainly put this in my backlog.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible, of course. But as far as I know it would need some coding to write custom solution. I would start with try to write and integrate custom 'life time manager' (in unity nomenclature), or create custom factory for subject service and register it as singleton.